# Physics 3 recommended book with solutions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, resource-recommendations, thermal-radiation, plasma-physics

I'm new to this forum and wanted to ask for a recommendation for a book which has these subjects with problems and solutions:(if this is not a valid question please tell me)

-Intro to Waves

-Fourier and Plasma

-Waveguide and Polarization

-Interference

-Bragg & Blackbody Radiation

-Blackbody Radiation

-Photoelectric Effect

-De-Broglie and Rutherford

-Bohr and Wave Function

any book you know?